# Require count occurance of a field in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column where some values are listed, I want to count occurrence of a combination strings

```
RowNo  DT1-Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept

1  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing  DT  Drives;#ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning;#
2  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing DT Drives;# 
3  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long;#
4  ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long
```

I have to count the occurrences, my desired output is

```
DT1-Increased_CT_Reason_Start_to_Accept                   count  

ERIC_Drive Test Taking too Long                            4  
ERIC_Lack Of GSC Resources/Queuing  DT Drives              2
ERIC_Cluster Having Too Many RF Issues Needing Tuning      1
```

Comment: Are these combination strings in different rows? If yes then applying Group By you can get the desired output

Comment: No it is not in different rows. combination is in same rows

Comment: how many max ';#' in each row ?

Comment: Actually It can be any number however I have observed only 3 as if now

Comment: Sometimes I have observed that # is also not available at the end , this case will happen when only one reason is available.

Comment: Try to split your row and then apply group by. try these solutions to split http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows